# Не получается запарсить значение ключа многомерного массива

Tags: jquery, ajax

Делаю ajax-запрос к API:

```js
function getImageURL(data) {
  var city = data;
  var link;
  //console.log(city);
  var requestURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=dd7db2cb607c16d11c25c747acde0c06&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&sort=relevance&safe_search=1&per_page=1&text=' + city + '%20City';
  //console.log(requestURL);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: requestURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //$('#test_block').append(JSON.stringify(data));
      var json = data;
      link = 'https://farm' + json.photos.photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + json.photos.photo.server + '/' + json.photos.photo.id + '_' + json.photos.photo.secret + '.jpg';
    }
  });
  console.log(link);

}
getImageURL('Kiev');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В теле success пытаюсь сгенерировать ссылку из полученной json-строки:

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":29667,"perpage":1,"total":"29667","photo":[{"id":"4451791182","owner":"35430600@N06","secret":"404c6073aa","server":"4058","farm":5,"title":"Kiev City","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"}
```

Но при попытке вывести в консоль значение переменной link получаю undefined. Как это исправить?

Comment: undefined из-за того, что у вас объявлена переменная `link` без значения, а jquery ajax запрос не перезаписывает внешнюю переменную. Как перезаписать внешнюю переменную я не знаю. Еще у вас ошибка, когда получаете ответ в ajax, должно быть так `link = 'https://farm' + json.photos.photo`[0]`.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + json.photos.photo`[0]`.server + '/' + json.photos.photo`[0]`.id + '_' + json.photos.photo`[0]`.secret + '.jpg';`

Comment: *асинхронность* - не используйте переменную `link` до того, как выполнится обработчик `success`

Comment: @greybutton - "ajax запрос не перезаписывает внешнюю переменную" - перезаписывает, только происходит это позже того, как выполняется `console.log(link);`.

Comment: @greybutton Возможно, я не до конца его понял.